# How would Schroedinger's cat "see" the world?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thought-experiment, schroedingers-cat

My question is about a "philosophical" implication of the copenhagen interpretation:

Schroedinger's cat sits in a box in a superposition state, until it interferes with the rest of the universe and decoherence occurs.
The whole universe, except this box, interferes with itself and thus enables a "common ground truth" to form, such that we can say: "this cat is in a superposition, we're not".

But everything inside the box is interfering with each other as well, disconnected from the rest of the universe, and thus enables an alternative "common ground truth", such that the cat would say: "the rest of the universe is in a superposition, I am not".

So how are we to say that anything is or isn't objectively in a superposition?

Comment: Well, a cat’s eyes aren’t open that much, so I’d say the see the world sparingly...

Comment: The cat is never in a superposition. There is only the possibility of two states.

Comment: see my answesr here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382968/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat-question/382995#382995   and here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500652/how-can-schr%c3%b6dingers-cat-be-both-dead-and-alive/500797#500797  ..